# How to fix AttributeError: 'Like' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a condition to my notification to check if a user's total number of likes for all the posts related to him and send a notification if reached a certain number. I have filtered the total likes by the post author but I keep receiving `AttributeError: 'Like' object has no attribute 'filter'`

To summarize here is the post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author')
    num_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='No. of Likes')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='liked', blank=True)
```

Here is the likes model

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(choices=LIKE_CHOICES,
                             default='Like', max_length=8)
    def like_progress(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        like = instance.filter(post__author=Post.author).count()
        post = like.post
        sender = like.user

        if like == 12:
            notify = Notification(post=post, sender=sender,
                                  user=post.author, notification_type=3)
            notify.save()

post_save.connect(Like.like_progress, sender=Like)
```

**My Question: How to fix this error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are calling a Model's function on an instance. I recommend you read about the [Django queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/).

Basically that error happens because the `filter()` function can be used from a model's [manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/) or an existing [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/), and you are using it from an instance of the model.

Here's a quick example to make it clearer:

This is a queryset, you can get one by using a model's manager aka the `objects` attribute.

```
from myapp.models import MyModel

queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(my_attribute=True)
```

The resulting queryset can be further filtered

```
queryset2 = queryset.filter(some_other_attribute=False)
```

Now to put it simple, a queryset can be seem as a list of instances. In this example from the `MyModel`'s model and you can get any instance from the queryset or iterate the queryset and go through all the instances.

```
instance_1 = queryset2.first()
instance_2 = queryset2.last()

# or

for instance in queryset2:
    print('This is an instance', instance)
```

Instances do not have the same `filter()` functionality as a manager or a queryset as they are a single element that cannot be filtered further.

So this this will raise an AttributeError

```
try:
    instance_1.filter(my_attribute=False)
except AttributeError:
    pritn("This won't work!")
```

So getting to your example, the correct way to do it should look something like this:

```
def like_progress(sender, instance, created=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # You may want to stop this if the objects was updated and not created.
        if not created:
            return
        # get all likes from the author
        qs_likes = Like.objects.filter(post__author=instance.author)
        likes_count = qs_likes.count()
        # You can get the post and the sender from the current instance
        post = instance.post
        sender = instance.user

        if likes_count == 12:
            notify = Notification.objects.create(post=post, sender=sender,
                                                 user=post.author, notification_type=3)
```

On a side note, you should not be connecting Model's functions the signals as they do receive different arguments in different order. So just define `like_progress` outside the model.

Answer (score 1):

```
like = instance.filter(post__author=Post.author).count()
```

You should use `filter` this way:

```
like = Like.objects.filter(post__author=post.author).count() 
#note that it should be post.author not Post.author
```

This will eliminate your current errors, but I doubt you can achieve what you want. I guess what you are trying to do is whenever there is a like instance saved, you want to count the number of conts that the post.author received, and if the like-count is 12, you send a notification.

But the `like_progress` is a method, are you going to call it by `like.like_progress`?

Comment: I am using signals for it `post_save.connect(Like.like_progress, sender=Like)`

Comment: first when I use your code `post` not `Post` I received `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'post' referenced before assignment`

Comment: when I amend it to `Post` I receive `TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ForwardManyToOneDescriptor object at 0x04963D90>.`

Comment: I think it will be better if you ask this using different title and format. You will ask how to implement like notification feature, and show all your related model and views and what you tried so far. I remember you had earlier questions about this...

Comment: yes it was in the views part but this is a different part related to notifications when I am trying to set it as a function when a certain number of total likes reached and notification takes place

Comment: Since you want to send notification when the post author receives total of 12 likes regardless which posts, you should put likes_received as a property of a user. And the sender of this notification should be the admin, right? Because it does not matter who was the last one liked this author’s any one of the posts.

Comment: No problem try implementing this way and see if you have any question. The rough flow could be set like_received property (works like a method), and when someone liked a post, post_save signal is called, you will first determine post’s author, then call this authors like_received property, then if it is 12, admin sends notification.